# Setting multiple graphs to a same base

Tags: graph, normalization, data-science

I would like to compare the graphs, but my data seem to be not collebrated. How do I get them to the same base? That is I want them all to be "grounded" at the same level. 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsFKn.png)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with python. Anyway, in order how to compare data depends a lot on the data itself and how you acquire it. Without knowing this, you could probably use an average of the last x-points in every dataset (the part where the line is very flat on the right side) and subtract this from the specific data to horizontally offset your data to a given y-position.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't, I removed that tag. And thanks for the advice how to find the offset!

Comment: You're welcome. So, is the question solved or is there any remaining concern? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, it solves it so far. I thought there was a mathematical algorithm for calculating the common baseline between the graphs, but it can be solved this way too